# Fix regular expression in htaccess mod rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using htaccess to redirect a list of outdated URLs.

Instead of discriminating one by one I'm trying to find the regular expression to transform this kind of URLs:

```
/gestao/contabilidade/item/2603-funções-do-departamento-financeiro.html
/financas/item/2603-funções-do-departamento-financeiro.html
```

Into this one:

```
/item/2603-funções-do-departamento-financeiro.html
```

So, the rule is to eliminate everything before the `'/item/'` - Except for those URLs that don't contain the `'/item/'` in them.

I tried different expressions using `RewriteRule` but couldn't find the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this rule in the beggining of your htaccess (in root folder)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.+/item/(.+)$ /item/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but not all the Urls start with gestao/contabilidade/ - Please see my edited question above.

Comment: Sorry, please see my edited answer, should be working as you want

Comment: That is converting: /gestao/item/6886-henri-fayol-pai-da-teoria-clássica-da-administração.html  Into: /item/gestao

Comment: Funny, some redirects are working OK, others are not. For example: http://www.portal-gestao.com/gestao/item/6886-henri-fayol-pai-da-teoria-clássica-da-administração.html is being redirected to http://www.portal-gestao.com/item/gestao which returns a 404

Comment: That's because it is in your browser's cache since you tried my first code. Try the same link with another browser (or clear your cache) and all links will work

Answer (score 0):

[You don't a actually need `mod_rewrite` to do this.](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/WhenNotToUseRewrite) You can do it more simply with `mod_redirect`.

```
RedirectMatch ^.+/item/(.+)$ /item/$1
```

Comment: Thanks, that is returning a "Redirection cycle" error

Comment: Good catch, thanks. I'll edit - briefly, if we match for *something* before the `/item/` section, it will ignore the ones with `/item/` at the beginning of the URL. Justin's pattern does that and now I understand why.